# Liquibase defaultValue json

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

How can I add a defaultValue for my json type column?

```
[
   "my_Num", "my_Hex"
]
```

Quotes that are used in json ("value") interfere with insertion

Error: Attribute my_Num and my_Hex is not allowed here

```
<changeSet id="1691141490000-1" author="">
<addColumn tableName="test">
  <column name="modules" type="json" defaultValue="["my_Num", "my_Hex"]">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
</addColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create file my_function.sql and insert:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMyJson() RETURNS json AS $$
SELECT json_build_array('hex', 'dex');
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Insert function in DB:

```
<changeSet id="1000502490000-1" author="" dbms="postgresql">
  <sqlFile path=".../my_function.sql"
     splitStatements="false"/>
</changeSet>
```

Usage:

```
addColumn tableName="test">
  <column name="myJson" type="json" defaultValueComputed="getMyJson()">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
</addColumn>
```